# Where is "Auto Layout Help" topic?

Tags: ios, macos, autolayout, documentation

I'm reading [Autolayout guideline/documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1).

And I often see info like:

> For more information, see Setting the Placeholder Intrinsic Size for a
>   Custom View in Auto Layout Help.

But I can't understand where this "Auto Layout Help" is?

Also I'll be thankful for an advice about more appropriate topic. May be other stackexchange resource or different tags... This is the question about iOS documentation, which is probably mostly readable by developers.  So I've decided to place it here with current tags.. But I might be wrong.

P.S.

Sorry for probably strange question and thanks for attention.

Comment: Seems to be a bug on documentation

Comment: I'll be surprised if you are right. But it might be so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the menu bar, choose Help > Xcode Help.
2. In the Xcode Help window, type “placeholder intrinsic size” into the search box.
3. Click on “Set the placeholder intrinsic size for a view”.

You can also find it online here: http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva9cacea30